# Keep the records by first date occurred and Name in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a data frame that have columns of **ID**, **Date**, **Code** and **Names**. I have multiple entries of ID at different dates with similar or different values in **Names** column. Below is the example.

```
ID       Date        Code      Names
1     2010-12-09     1.1.1     Alpha
1     2010-12-15     1.1.1     Alpha
1     2010-12-15     1.1.1     Beta
2     2010-12-09     1.1.1     Beta
2     2010-12-17     1.1.1     Beta
3     2011-02-09     1.1.1     Gamma
3     2011-04-25     1.1.1     Gamma
4     2011-04-25     1.1.1     Tango
```

I want to keep the rows by **ID** that occurred first by **date** and **Names**. Delete the rest with different dates and similar **names**. Below is the example of my resultant dataframe.

```
ID       Date        Code      Names
1     2010-12-09     1.1.1     Alpha
1     2010-12-09     1.1.1     Beta
2     2010-12-09     1.1.1     Beta
3     2011-02-09     1.1.1     Gamma
6     2011-04-25     1.1.1     Tango
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `slice_min`:

```r
library(dplyr)
slice_min(your_df, Date, by = c(ID, Names))

#   ID       Date  Code Names
# 1  1 2010-12-09 1.1.1 Alpha
# 2  1 2010-12-15 1.1.1  Beta
# 3  2 2010-12-09 1.1.1  Beta
# 4  3 2011-02-09 1.1.1 Gamma
# 5  4 2011-04-25 1.1.1 Tango
```

Comment: it gives error   "slice_min() ! '... ' must be empty" x:Problemetic Argument

Comment: Check that you've replaced `your_df` by the name of your data.fame, and also that you have `dplyr 1.1.0`. Otherwise, just reinstall the packages: `install.packages("dplyr")`

Comment: @I did both, still the same error. Not sure where is the problem.

Comment: it works now. I updated my dplyr package. I guess the old package was not working on slice_min function. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- fread("ID       Date        Code      Names
1     2010-12-09     1.1.1     Alpha
1     2010-12-15     1.1.1     Alpha
1     2010-12-15     1.1.1     Beta
2     2010-12-09     1.1.1     Beta
2     2010-12-17     1.1.1     Beta
3     2011-02-09     1.1.1     Gamma
3     2011-04-25     1.1.1     Gamma
4     2011-04-25     1.1.1     Tango")

dt[dt[, .I[which.min(Date)], by = .(ID, Names)]$V1]

#    ID       Date  Code Names
# 1:  1 2010-12-09 1.1.1 Alpha
# 2:  1 2010-12-15 1.1.1  Beta
# 3:  2 2010-12-09 1.1.1  Beta
# 4:  3 2011-02-09 1.1.1 Gamma
# 5:  4 2011-04-25 1.1.1 Tango
```

Comment: It gives error. unused argument ( by = .(ID, Names))